# missing a step in windows server 2008 FTP set up

Tags: windows-server-2008, ftp

I have a similar directory set up to this: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/301/creating-a-new-ftp-site/#01

if the ftp site 'my new ftp site' has a number of folders underneath it such as 'images', 'media' - how do I set up ftp://media.mydomain.com on the media folder?

- I have created a user named 'media' and set the password.
- In the DNS Manager i have set up media.mydomain as a Host [A] record.
- In IIS I have set up ftp authorization rules for the media user (read/write).

Any ideas what would be preventing me from connecting to ftp://media.mydomain.com using the credentials of the media user?

Answer (score 1):

> if the ftp site 'my new ftp site' has a number of folders underneath it such as 'images', 'media' - how do I set up ftp://media.mydomain.com on the media folder?

You should be able to do this with IIS 7.x the same way you add a host header value to a Website under IIS.  Off the top of my head, it should be right-click > Bindings... or perhaps Properties.  You'll also need to set `useDomainAsHostName` to true; details [here](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.ftpServer/serverRuntime/hostNameSupport).